# jQuery .trigger() method causes deep recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I made a custom lightbox. Calling it's close method triggers the close event directly on the Lightbox object. Using `.trigger()` in the close method causes a significant delay before the lightbox closes and makes the page unresponsive when trying to close the lightbox. I know from analyzing the function in the dev tools while it runs that the close method is being called recursively, but it does NOT throw a "Too much recursion" error.

Using jQuery's `.triggerHandler()` method does not cause this recursion problem. I know from this and also from looking through the code that none of the event listeners for the close event are calling the Lightbox's `close()` method. Also, using the exact same technique in the Lightbox's `open()` method, with `open.lb` for the event name, doesn't cause any problems.

Here is the code for the Lightbox class's `close()` method.

```
close: function (callback) {
  this.opened = false;
  var self = this;
  this.$self.trigger('close.lb');
  this.cover
        .stop()
        .animate({opacity: 0}, Lightbox.ANIMATION_SPEED);
    this.element
        .stop()
        .animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height:  0
        }, Lightbox.ANIMATION_SPEED, function () {
          self.cover.add(self.element).removeClass('active');
          if (callback) {
            callback();
          }
        });
},
```

I looked at the code for jQuery's `.trigger()` method, but it's pretty dense.

Comment: There's not enough code here to see quite how your lightbox works but are you sure the trigger isn't calling the close method again in some way and causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, definitely. If that were the case then calling `.triggerHandler()` instead of `.trigger()` should have the same effect. Also, the loop isn't infinite SOMETIMES.
Yesterday when I tested I didn't get any errors at all, but just now I got errors most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself appears to be causing the recursion.

Note the difference here. `.trigger()` causes to occur the very action that triggers the event handlers to fire, whereas `.triggerHandler()` only fires the event handlers. I'm surprised jQuery figures to look for a `.close()` method when I `.trigger()` the close event, but that nevertheless is what's occurring.

http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/